# Formula field as the error location for a validation rule

Tags: validation, salesforce

We have some formula fields which mirror data from other objects. We've also got validation rules that, in certain conditions, require particular values for these formula fields.

Sometimes we'd like for validation rule errors to show up on the formula field, but it looks like Salesforce doesn't allow - by default - formula fields to be the "Error Location" for validation rules.

Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: How well do you know triggers?

Comment: Rather than writing the validation rule, you can mimic the rules in an update trigger.  If all of the rules are met, you can change the value of the formula field.